# Factory narrowing inside switch statement

Tags: typescript, factory, narrowing

Is it possible to narrow type output of a factory create method by literal types?
I've managed to get some narrowing with if statements and discriminated unions, but this is creational method so I'm not sure whether it's possible.

```
class Radio {
    type: "RADIO"; // literal type 
    title: string = "A value";
    selected: boolean = false;

    constructor(radio?: Radio) {

    }
}    

class OptionFactory {
    static create({
        type,
        price = 1.0,
        title = "Option",
        selected = false,
    }: {
        price: number;
        title: string;
        selected: boolean;
    }) {
        switch (type) {
            case "RADIO":
                return new Radio({
                    title,
                    selected,
                    // price,
                });
            case "CHECKBOX":
                return new Checkbox({
                    title,
                    selected,
                    // price,
                });
            case "PRICEOPTION":
                return new PriceOption({
                    title,
                    selected,
                    price,
                });
        }
    }
}

let radioButtons = new Array<Radio>();

tags.push(OptionFactory.create({ type: "RADIO" })); //error ts(2345)

console.log(tags);
```

[Typescript Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBKYBMCWB7aBvAUNH0AuAngA4CmAXNAESwCCAIgJIDylA3NAPQfQhJ4kAnMCHzES0bLjx8Q5aBDwCkAOwDm0ALxUa0AG7CAriTaScEErOD8EFAEYoUssMs3QAZsPOtMp6MBTKCgIGVigCABRCyCgA-BTw0QCUGD640AC+mJmYoJAwAMIAFiTAANb2AB4paYSkFJT5ABIAovkA0gBCTAAabJzcvPxCIrXivtJ4shRBKupalDr6IEYmaeaW1nYOTi5aHiBeqbj+gYoheGHhwMVllXHQRSXlKBXJWL6Z2blQ0AAKSsASEwiNIAtUpGJ6r9YAx8s0mL8ACrMAByfS4PD4gmEolIEhqMjkMzUrgWekMxm8awsJU20HsjhIzlc+0OaSIALkygMAFtbIJXABGAB0AAZvL4TkFzpcOUhAcDQcp7v95UCQahlG8jjhPj5vjBFZqAGJgUICAjgsx4MDSYB+ARM-jhLBpGpiAA0vnZnKFYq9bqkhNJRoClADgfkNKsJAQLM8JAjuoorsjcsBFG5fMEVMjEym8kUs1zgfWtNjW0ZzhLGW1kfkAHc+NdoOFRnX68dIOJqPRmJQyN7OzhHXgDAIXMoSA24IhUC6h8OCZNE4ul2Zo9Yk+u3Rj06ud7h0oka-XgN2qE1Wp0egO1-XR+PJ9OHjdnhUF4fA-mD1-qRtY23P8905ICl2PU9I3PcwqGhWF4SRVE7z-R8J2gKcZ1VBUNQCT8-yDFcwMPMsYwQIid33cj6wgtdMjSPVMFkPBoCiVAOgMPALkCVwMOgGgBCEAgAB4ElQAA+cITx8G1VAgYUiAMCBCnCUNlFNc0CGFYBHVtEgXVxORe0YFhaxPfpBAEMJ8AgcIACYAGYABYAFZEn1AIIEZYUQBQVQ2zAWSTyAA)

Comment: I copy + pasted your code into the TS playground and then included a link to it in your question. If you follow the link, you can see that there are several errors. Will you please address all of them that you can and then click the _Share_ button in the playground to get an updated link, and then update your question with it? That way, potential answerers can focus on the actual problem.

Comment: @jsejcksn Sorry, I thought the playground link was added automatically, so I removed it during edit.

Comment: I'm not sure if you reference to the same meaning of the word "narrowing" as I do, could you give an example of the `if` statement where you could manage to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: @steakoverflow I think by "narrowing" you mean "having the compiler return a type of a specific instance of one of the classes based on the value of the literal `type` discriminator string". If that's right, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71360837/438273).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this...

```ts
function createFrom({ type, price = 1.0, title = "Option", selected = false }: CreationOptions): FactoryReturn {
  return factoryMap[type]({ price, title, selected });
}

const factoryMap: FactoryMap = {
  "RADIO": ({ title, selected }: Titleable & Selectable) => {
    return new Radio({ title, selected });
  },
  "CHECKBOX": ({ title, selected }: Titleable & Selectable) => {
    return new Checkbox({ title, selected });
  },
  "PRICEOPTION": ({ price, title, selected }: Titleable & Selectable & Priceable) => {
    return new PriceOption({ price, title, selected });
  }
}

type Typeable = { type: keyof FactoryMap };
type Priceable = { price?: number };
type Titleable = { title?: string };
type Selectable = { selected?: boolean };
type FactorySelector = Extract<CreationOptions, Typeable>;
type FactoryReturn = ReturnType<FactoryMap[FactorySelector["type"]]>;

type CreationOptions = Typeable & Priceable & Titleable & Selectable;

type RadioConstructor = (option: Titleable & Selectable) => Radio;
type CheckboxConstructor = (option: Titleable & Selectable) => Checkbox;
type PriceOptionConstructor = (option: Titleable & Selectable & Priceable) => PriceOption;

type FactoryMap = {
  "RADIO": RadioConstructor,
  "CHECKBOX": CheckboxConstructor,
  "PRICEOPTION": PriceOptionConstructor
}

class Radio {
  constructor(option: Titleable & Selectable) {
    console.log('[Radio]', '[constructor]', option);
  }
}

class Checkbox {
  constructor(option: Titleable & Selectable) {
    console.log('[Checkbox]', '[constructor]', option);
  }
}

class PriceOption {
  constructor(option: Titleable & Selectable & Priceable) {
    console.log('[PriceOption]', '[constructor]', option);
  }
}

console.log(createFrom({ type: "RADIO" }));
console.log(createFrom({ type: "CHECKBOX" }));
console.log(createFrom({ type: "PRICEOPTION" }));
```

---

### ***`WYSIWYG`*** => ***`WHAT YOU SHOW IS WHAT YOU GET`***

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option which reorganizes your classes and provides a factory function which infers the type of class instance from the `"type"` property provided in the init:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgeTMAlgewHYElvrBQC8UA3gLABQUUSANhAMbAQAmAXFAEaaaNxsAbmq0MwRlwTAATumwBzEVQC+y6k3qIEsRCjRZsAHgAq4aBAAerbGx3S5igHzlRdCIxbsuvfhEHKYoSSdLLySm4y-mw49CBQoJBcZpDqNFBMOA4AriyYMlAAFPKEXPBIqBg4+IRQAGTkCebJ5kJQKgCUruliABboCAB0DMysbCRQJcDDHqPsgbQJ-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-n+AEmE4HRcGR0LAJREDUbR9GMcxkWNs2ZArhMACMFrBIePyfj8JKIWMEz2XA9BID2pBTAsCAAO6EEwvQakc+yQHqPQZHoAknnaPxcFEwDZDI2BQOZjVieynJ4mV7D5RIEANogUCCCA-ZMH1Ck3tO96xsNECjeNk0QNN6lep+eIrqVsxIUtjCrToG1bTtL5UkdJ0TVNRmPFgeJbHdnhjM963YJt+pQGwECVdk9DAFwi40dNv3ijING4j8+AWVV6DjCcPy2ekdJ2dQAD05NQOKliMWAazZAgcAKMmdnNiuXmkG5-ieYGgPjrtU53rODpUBzgaddAlPXkLymxtQ4tCsuSZQNLqZwTIbNZEQMj-ZgCBcMZWAANoALoTGbyjNrrJkTNzHmafzZL6VSos21gQxgIzvSFO7mDE9QfuS6rVMu6Cgd6zMIPsCHoSOAoEcmZsBWxzhih2UH2XkwAVNTliQEhLwY+qgC8G4AsjtQ7QAB+Nc19QHqYDioDkiu54xBAOjYJgRBWAMRA4KS0B-HrPyDIUABMADMk8AJxdNn5PUEAA)

```ts
type BaseOptionInit = {
  selected: boolean;
  title: string;
};

class BaseOption<Type extends string> {
  selected: boolean;
  title: string;
  readonly type: Type;

  constructor (init: BaseOptionInit & { type: Type; }) {
    this.selected = init.selected;
    this.title = init.title;
    this.type = init.type;
  }
}

class Radio extends BaseOption<'RADIO'> {
  constructor (init: BaseOptionInit) {
    super({...init, type: 'RADIO'});
  }
}

class Checkbox extends BaseOption<'CHECKBOX'> {
  constructor (init: BaseOptionInit) {
    super({...init, type: 'CHECKBOX'});
  }
}

class PriceOption extends BaseOption<'PRICEOPTION'> {
  price: number;
  constructor (init: BaseOptionInit & { price: number; }) {
    const {price, ...rest} = init;
    super({...rest, type: 'PRICEOPTION'});
    this.price = price;
  }
}

type OptionType = 'CHECKBOX' | 'PRICEOPTION' | 'RADIO';

type OptionFactoryInit<T extends OptionType> = {
  price?: number;
  selected?: boolean;
  title?: string;
  type: T;
}

type OptionInstanceFromTypeName<T extends OptionType> = (
  T extends 'CHECKBOX' ? Checkbox
  : T extends 'PRICEOPTION' ? PriceOption
  : T extends 'RADIO' ? Radio
  : never
);

function createOption <T extends OptionType>(init: OptionFactoryInit<T>): OptionInstanceFromTypeName<T> {
  const {price = 1, title = 'Option', selected = false} = init;
  switch (init.type) {
    case 'CHECKBOX': return new Checkbox({selected, title}) as any;
    case 'PRICEOPTION': return new PriceOption({price, selected, title}) as any;
    case 'RADIO': return new Radio({title, selected}) as any;
    default: throw new Error('Invalid type');
  }
}


// Example usage:

const priceOption = createOption({type: 'PRICEOPTION'});
priceOption.type // 'PRICEOPTION'
priceOption.price // number

const radios: Radio[] = [];
const radio = createOption({type: 'RADIO'});
radios.push(radio);

radio.type // 'RADIO'
radio.selected // string
radio.title // string

radio.price /* Expected error 
      ~~~~~
Property 'price' does not exist on type 'Radio'.(2339) */
```